# Problems with LCD initialization: 4-bit mode

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, code

I have this microcontroler with this LCD(DEM16216) mounted on it which I cannot initialize.

Only 4 of the pins are connected, thus it runs in a 4 bit mode (I think?). I found the datasheet for it (DEM16216) , which gives an step by step guide on how to do it, but for some reason it does not work for me...

Could someone tell me why this isn't working for me?

This is the [datasheet for my LCD](http://www.gaw.ru/pdf/lcd/lcm/Display/char/DEM16216SYH-LY.PDF).

The one my teacher recommended was [this one](http://web.alfredstate.edu/weimandn/lcd/lcd_initialization/lcd_initialization_index.html).

Complete code can be downloaded from 
[code]http://speedy.sh/vZJby/LCD-init-code.zip[/code]

`init` is performed outside of a superloop, while command is performed inside a superloop.

Could anyone explain why this isn't working?

screen.c

```
#include"screen.h"

void nibble_value(INT8U binary_value)
{
    if((binary_value & 0b00001000) == 8)      //DB7
        GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R |= (0b00100000);
    else
        GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R &= ~(0b00100000);

        if((binary_value & 0b00000100) == 4)    //DB6
            GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R |= (0b00010000);
        else
            GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R &= ~(0b00010000);

            if((binary_value & 0b00000010) == 2)    //DB5
                  GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R |= (0b00001000);
            else
                    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R &= ~(0b00001000);

                if((binary_value & 0b00000001) == 1)    // DB4
                    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R |= (0b00000100);
                else
                    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R &= ~(0b00000100);

}
void enable_pin (int a)
{
    if (a)
    {
        GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R |= (0b01000000); //Disables "enable "pin

        redLed(ON); //Debug
    }

    else{
        GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R &= ~(0b01000000); // Enables  "enable" pin

                redLed(OFF); //debug
    }
}


void screen_init( void )
{
     //POwer on
     //MILLISEC(100);
    enable_pin(OFF);
    yellowLed(ON);
    greenLed(OFF);
    redLed(OFF);
    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
    yellowLed(OFF);
    redLed(ON);
     // Special case Function set
//----------------------------------------------------------------//

    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00000011);  // DB5 = 1, DB4 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin off
    // MILLISEC(15);                // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00000011);          // DB5 = 1, DB4 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // Enable pin off
    // MILLISEC(15);                // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00000011);          // DB5 = 1, DB4 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin off
    // MILLISEC(5);             // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
     //initial Function set
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00000010);          // 0x02 = 0b00000010 => DB5 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);             // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
     //Function set
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00000010);          // 0x02 = 0b00000010 => DB5 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable  pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);             // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);             // 1 ms delay
     nibble_value(0b00001000);          // 0x8 = 0b00001000 n = 1 and f = 0 => DB7 = 1
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);             // 5 ms delay
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
     //Display On/Off
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
    // MILLISEC(1);             // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0x00);        // ZERO
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // delay 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);                 // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0b00001000);      // DB7  = 1 => display off
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // delay = 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//---------------------------------------------------------------//
     //Clear Display
//---------------------------------------------------------------//
    // MILLISEC(1);                 // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0b00000000);  // Zero
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // Enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // Delay  = 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);                 // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0b00000001);  // No configurable bits, CLEAR Display
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // delay = 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//---------------------------------------------------------------//
     //Entry Mode set
//---------------------------------------------------------------//
    // MILLISEC(1);                 // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0b00000000);  // Zero
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // Enable pin = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // Delay  = 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

    // MILLISEC(1);                 // delay = 1 ms
     nibble_value(0b00000110);  // DB6 = 1, DB5 = 1 (increment by 1) , DB4 = 0 (No shift)
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // enable = off
    // MILLISEC(5);                 // delay = 5 ms
        for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;

//---------------------------------------------------------------//
}

void command (void)
{
    //Command
//---------------------------------------------------------------//
     nibble_value(0b00000000);  // Zero
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // Enable pin off
    for(i=0; i<100; i++);

//--------------------------------------------------------------//
        //Command
//---------------------------------------------------------------//
     nibble_value(0b00001111);  // D  = 1, C = 1 , B = 1  => display on, cursor  on and blinking on..
     enable_pin(ON);            // enable pin on
     enable_pin(OFF);           // Enable pin off
    for(i=0; i<100; i++);

//--------------------------------------------------------------//
}
```

Main.c

```
#include "lm3s6965.h"
#include "systick.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "emp_type.h"
#include "swtimers.h"
#include "LED.h"
#include "screen.h"
int main(void)
{
     disable_global_int();
     init_clk_system();
     init_gpio();
     systick_init();
     enable_global_int();
     screen_init();
     INT16S alive_timer = MILLISEC(500);


    while(1)
    {
        redLed(ON);
        yellowLed(ON);
        greenLed(ON);
        while( !klik );
        klik--;
            if( ! --timer )
            {
                timer = MILLISEC( 500 );
                GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= 0x01;
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: It would help the readability a lot if you used #defines in your c code rather than a bunch of binary numbers.

Comment: Which 4 pins are connected?

Comment: RW(PA6),RS(PA7),D4(PB2),D5(PB3),D6(PB4),D7(PB5),E(PB6)

Comment: Are you sending the Function Set command to the instruction register? That is what controls the 4bit vs 8bit bus width.

Comment: I am not quite sure on how to respond to your question. 
The way my code works is,In Insert_value I insert a 8 bit value, and each bit is then map to each port, where the respective bit gets set or not. 



I use this function to initialize LCD, by using the function with different values.  As you can see. I am just doing what the datasheet say i should do.

Comment: I am not doing anything unusual.. This it how i i've writen to data of an port.

Comment: I think it maybe missing use of enable bit??
But the datasheet does not say anything about when it shall be on and off.. and so on.

Comment: Read the following two-part article(s):

http://www.wizard.org/auction_support/lcd1.pdf
http://www.wizard.org/auction_support/lcd2.pdf

I think they may help you a lot in tracking this down!

Comment: Table 12.2 in the LCD datasheet says that you need to send 0b0011 in 4-bit mode first. Looking at Section 11, this is the "Function Set" instruction. This sets the LCD screen to be in 4-bit mode. -- Also, are you sure that you are toggling the enable pin correctly? Your code is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: The enable hasn't been used.. I've tried to comment some of the things to make it more understandable.. Hope it helps. 

But as you are saying, i wasn't using enable pin before..

Comment: Just as a side note regarding good pratice and code readability: Prevent commenting on a per line basis WHAT the line does like "enable_pin(ON); // enable pin = on". THat should be (and is) self explanatory from the variable/function names in most cases. Instead, comment on things that are less obvious and one may ask WHY you did what you did. Like "Process init sequence" followed by the sequence of init commands.

Comment: I'd suggest taking Adafruit LCD library, dissecting it and adopting it to your needs. Then compare with your code to understand what were you doing wrong. Do you see anything on LCD? Is contrast adjusted correctly? Is RS pin at the correct voltage? You should get garbage on the screen if the problem is in the code only, if it's totally blank - it's connection problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the display, i've tested it with an another file, and the display clearly shows the message..
The display is just blank.

Comment: How about a schematic?

Comment: The pins are correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. are you setting the RS pin to the correct value?
2. You seem to think that you can use insert_value( x ) to write 8 bits to the LCD, but this must be done in two steps, like (assuming the 4 bits written by wrire4 are connected to the D7..D4 of your LCD):

   ```
   write4( b >> 4 );
   write4( b );
   ```
3. You must follow the 4-bit initalization as is shown in the initialization sequence as show in the datasheet EXACTLY, and note that each row in that initialization can imply two write4 commands.

Your insert_value command uses 2 bits of the value you pass to it for the RS and RW bits. Personally I prefer to keep RW on W all the time, and I pass RS as a separate argument. In your version it is very difficult to see what data you are passing to the LCD. But it is clear that you are writing 3 nibbles, where the datasheet specifies 4. This is my sequence:

```
      write4( 0x03 );
      timing::wait(  15 * timing::ms );
      write4( 0x03 );
      timing::wait(  100 * timing::us );
      write4( 0x03 );
      write4( 0x02 );     // 4 bit mode
```

A general note on debugging: when you have more than one problem, you can no longer reason "I changed this to to that and it did not work, hence that was not the good idea". It will only work when you have solved ALL problems.

Comment: When you send your nibble how do distiguish between high or low, or does it not matter??

To be honest, I don't see where I am going wrong with my codepiece..

Comment: @user38544 There are two things to think about there. The 4 bits are connected to 4 pins on the mcu and 4 pins on the lcd. Make sure that what you are calling d7-d4 flows to the LCD appropriately in hardware. The second thing is that you are sending one nibble and then the second. The order is determined by the datasheet.

Comment: @user35844 in your code you send 3 nibbles in the initialization (before on/off), the datasheet specifies 4. That might not be the only problem, but it sure is A problem.

Comment: But which one should i use the one i found, or the one my teacher gave..??

Comment: Up to you, if you choose wrong it is your problem :) What I show is what the datasheet specifies, and that works for me (it is also theoretically sound). You could browse the web for a few other 4-bit HD44780 libraries and check what they do.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen i've tried with your sequence and it still doesn't.. 

would it be more helpfull if i Uploaded my whole project ?

Comment: Could the problem be that i am writing to all the ports everytime, and not some of them which i would do if i wrote a nibble.. 

But since i am writing to 6 bits, how i do i define the high nibble and the low nibble, and what should each nibble include?

Comment: "So you would use the one my teacher has given me" are you kidding? BTW which microcontroller are you using? If it is a PIC you might be a victim of the RMW problem.

Comment: I've tried to initialize it using a nibble function,  where i only write to the DB7 - DB4 pins.. 

I Toggle the state of the enable pin each time i've send 2 nibbles. This means I do not write to RS or RW.

Comment: Think! If you toggle once every two nibbles, how is the LCD supposed to tell where one nibble ends and the next one starts? Don't think of E as an Enable, it is more like an Edge (in the sense of an edge-triggered register).

Comment: Ok.. i've changed it to change state for each nibble..
This is how i do it


enable(on),
Delay(5ms),
Nibble("value"),
Delay(5ms),
Enable(off),

And so on.. and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which uC are you using?

Comment: ohh.. you meant µC i am using LM3s6965..

Comment: I found this one..
http://joshuagalloway.com/lcd.html
can this be used, because it doesn't work for me..

Comment: That one uses 3,3,3,2. I use 3,3,3,2. The datasheet requires 3,3,3,2. Do you still wonder what the correct start sequence is?

Comment: I've tried so many... I don't know what to believe??

Comment: I rest my case.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the timing?
My delay arent precise. they are usualy around 6 ms.

Comment: When you say you do 3,3,3,2
Is you must be in nibble form, but how do you define high and low nibble when you only using 6 bits?

Comment: Those are nibbles: 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x2. After that, the interface is in 4-bit mode, and you can send 8-bit commands by sending first the high nibble, then the low nibble.

Comment: which ports do you write to when you send the high nibble and which do you write when you send your low nibble??

Comment: To the same 4 pins, that are connected to the D4-D7 of the LCD.

Comment: hmm.. that is exatly what i am doing.. The only thing i See could be the timing, my delay function only creates delays in ms and not µs.. but that shouldn't be a problem.. right??

Comment: Besides the little detail that you ARE NOT SENDING THE CORRECT 4 BIT INITIALIZATION SEQUENCE???

Comment: but when you write 0x3, your are not sending a nibble but 6 bits..

Is it still db7-db4 you are writing to, or is it just RS and R/W

Comment: "but when you write 0x3, your are not sending a nibble but 6 bits" No I am not. Please explain why you think so, that could be one of your problems.

Comment: 0x30 =  0b110000

Comment: Where did you read 0x30 ? I wrote 0x3 !

Comment: 0x3 = 0b11 , I misinterpreted is as 0x30 for 8 bit mode.. 
But i am doing exactly as you say and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Of course it does not work yet, you must weed out ALL bugs. Next step: take a better look at those  "if((binary_value << 3) == 1)" lines. And give use the FULL code, including main().

Comment: full code added

Comment: Did you correct those if statements?

Comment: Yes.. Those have been corrected. 
if((binary_value & 0b00001000) == 8)

Comment: And do you use the 3,3,3,2 sequence?

Comment: Yes.. My code is added

Comment: Yup, but that requires that I unzip and look through your code. Sorry, too lazy to do that.

Comment: The whole project is included, and main.c and screen.c is now visible here..